# Is it possible to get a user object or their id from their name and tag? [Discord.py]

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, discord.py

I searched around on google and could only find getting a user object from their id.

Is it possible to get a user object from their name and tag? So could i get a user object if the input is user#1234?

If it is not possible I would just like to know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the the member object using [`guild.get_member_named(NAMEHERE)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild%20get_member_named#discord.Guild.get_member_named)

```py
member = guild.get_member_named(NAMEHERE)
```

Note: if you are doing this in a command then use `ctx.guild` at the start if not use `guild = bot.get_guild(123)` where 123 is the guild id